# Matching Data in Column and then Update the Value

Tags: excel, vba

What i am Trying to do is match Invoice No. Sheet1's Column A with Sheet2's Column A and if match found then update the adjacent cell of Sheet1's Column B as "Found" .
but in sheet 2 data is stored like that

***Invoice No-FB256461416461***

***April-2020/FB256461416461(18/06/2020)/ABC SYSTEMS LIMITED/Information Tech Expense(in/out))***

My Code but ***problem is this if there are two invoices with no FB256461416461 & FB25646141646 it still matches because its just last 1 is missing***

```
Dim j As Double
Dim f As String
Dim lastrow As Double
Dim l As Double
Dim m As Double
l = 1
m = 1

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lastrow

Do While l < lastrow + 1
'MsgBox l
f = Cells(l, 1).Value
'MsgBox f
Set rgFound = Sheet2.Range("A1:A5000").Find(f, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

If rgFound Is Nothing Then
    'MsgBox "Name was not found."
    l = l + 1
Else
     'MsgBox "Name found in :" & rgFound.Address
    ' MsgBox l
     Cells(l, 3).Value = "Found"
   '  i = rgFound.Row
   '  j = rgFound.Column
     
'     Range("rgFound") = "Done"
      'Cells(i, j + 1).Value = "Done"
      l = l + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

'A double split on first "/" and then "(" should do the trick.

```
Sub x()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Dim i_array As Variant, inv_array As Variant, i As Long, lastrow As Long, r As Long, rng As Range

lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
r = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

On Error GoTo err1
For i = 1 To r
    i_array = VBA.Split(ws2.Cells(i, 1), "/")
    inv_array = VBA.Split(i_array(1), "(")
    ws2.Cells(i, 5).Value = inv_array(0)
x:
Next i

Set rng = ws2.Range("E1:E" & r)

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws1.Cells(i, 1), rng, False)) Then ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Found"
Next i

Exit Sub
err1:
Resume x
End Sub
```

Comment: getting error in line----

inv_array = VBA.Split(i_array(1), "(")

Error- SubScript Out of range

Comment: My assumption: Every cell value in the range on sheet 2 follows this structure: April-2020/FB256461416461(18/06/2020)/ABC SYSTEMS LIMITED/Information Tech Expense(in/out)). So my guessis  that their are either 1) empty rows within the range on sheet 2 or 2) cell values without a "/". I've edited error handling for these two cases so it will go to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your logic.

I would suggest you try something like:

1. If the Invoice number is of fixed length, try to code taking this into consideration.
2. You can get advantage of that "(" character which is denoting the end of invoice to get the correct invoice number.

I will keep you posted if something else comes to my mind.

Comment: Invoices no and length is totally random mix of alphabet and numbers , and yes I extracted invoice no by formula and then used it for exact matching , that I have already done , I was thinking if it's possible directly match it

Comment: Could you please post the formula which you used to extract invoice no?